# PIR sensor Cracked on two of my outdoor lights and the other shattered. Allen & Roth from Lowes. No support at all

Tags: lighting

Good Day, I have been trying to find a replacement for my 3 motion sensor light PIR lenses. But Have had no luck. I read about using the milk carton plastic and this seems to be the only option I have unless replacing all 3 at $70 each. Any ideas or solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: a milk carton won't have the proper lensing patterns in the plastic. it will work, but range/consistency will be less than ideal. better to pull plastic from a busted motion detector that has the grooves needed to build up local contrast and allow good operation.

Answer (score 3):

It appears Allen & Roth is a "house brand" of Lowes, meaning Lowes buyers visit Shenzhen and go around to Chinese makers and wheel and deal to get things like this made as a limited run. However in their defense, they make the manufacturer build to US safety standards and secure a <strike>UL listing</strike> ETL listing for the item.  Because US *retailers* are required to do that.

You are correct, that for a Code legal repair, you are out of luck since no service or parts are available.  That's the downside of the nice price.

The milk jug hack is probably as good as you're going to do. I suppose if you care about the aesthetic, you could try to hunt the lens down on Alibaba/AliExpress, with the caution not to buy *anything else* mains-powered from that junkstream because it's unsafe.  <del>UL</del> ETL cleared that PIR lens, because it's their job to protect you from unsafe junk, not unreliable junk.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem and I don't like buying a new sensor for want of a $0.01 piece of plastic.  Yes, I've found that a piece cut from a milk jug seems to work perfectly for me.

Comment: I've also used the milk jug plastic, low fat.. LOL,  for motion sensors. The original lenses  cracked way to soon in this Florida sun.+

Comment: I’ve found that a cheap £1 clear plastic measuring jug works a treat once measured and cut with scissors

Answer (score 1):

Many security companies carry spares.
https://securitydistributors.com.au/product/curtain-lens-for-slim-pir-slim-dual/

regards, ash

Comment: Ash, you are required to declare your affiliation to linked sites.  It is okay if you are, but you are required to declare either way.